# Why does a yield from inside __next__() return generator object?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I am using `yield` to return the next value in the `__next__()` function in my class. However it does not return the next value, it returns the generator object.

I am trying to better understand iterators and `yield`. I might be doing it in the wrong way.

Have a look.

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s=s

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        for i in range(len(self.s)):
            yield(self.s[i])

r=MyString("abc")
i=iter(r)
print(next(i))
```

This returns:

`generator object __next__ at 0x032C05A0`

Comment: [`__next__` returns the next item in the iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) so making `__next__` a generator doesn't really make sense, or well it means that every value of your `MyString` iterator is a generator.

Comment: MyString should not define `__next__`. `__next__` is for iterators, not iterables. Similarly, it should not `return self` for `__iter__`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`next` pretty much just calls `__next__()` in this case.  Calling `__next__` on your object will start the generator and return it (no magic is done at this point).

---

In this case, you *might* be able to get away with not defining `__next__` at all:

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s=s

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(len(self.s)):
            yield(self.s[i])
        # Or...
        # for item in self.s:
        #     yield item
```

If you wanted to use `__iter__` and `__next__` (to define an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) rather than simply making an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)), you'd probably want to do something like this:

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s
        self._ix = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._ix is None:
            self._ix = 0

        try:
            item = self.s[self._ix]
        except IndexError:
            # Possibly reset `self._ix`?
            raise StopIteration
        self._ix += 1
        return item
```

Comment: I had not seen the recent edit. Was asking why it was missing

Comment: @MosesKoledoye -- Yeah, it was an oversight in the original post that I corrected while you were commenting.  I also realized that calling `iter(mystring)` probably shouldn't reset the iteration ... Thanks for watchin' my back.  :-)

Answer (score 16):

Let's take a look at the purpose of the `__next__` method. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__):

> iterator.__next__()
>
> Return the next item from the container. If there are no further items, raise the StopIteration exception.

Now let's see what the `yield` statement does. Another excerpt from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr):

> Using a yield expression in a function’s body causes that function to
>   be a generator

And

> When a generator function is called, it returns an iterator known as a
>   generator.

Now compare `__next__` and `yield`: `__next__` **returns the next item from the container**. But a function containing the `yield` keyword **returns an iterator**. Consequently, using `yield` in a `__next__` method results in an iterator that yields iterators.

---

If you want to use `yield` to make your class iterable, do it in the [`__iter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method:

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

    def __iter__(self):
        for s in self.s:
            yield s
```

The `__iter__` method is supposed to return an iterator - and the `yield` keyword makes it do exactly that.

---

For completeness, here is how you would implement an iterator with a `__next__` method. You have to keep track of the state of the iteration, and return the corresponding value. The easiest solution is probably to increment an index every time `__next__` is called:

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s = s
        self.index = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.index += 1

        if self.index >= len(self.s):
            raise StopIteration

        return self.s[self.index]
```

Comment: Would you not be required to do `self.index = -1` on `def __iter__(self)` to reset the iteration, then, when called later or nested as `for a in list... for b in list... if a!=b...`

Comment: @user Well, objects that are their own iterators usually don't reset in the `__iter__` method. Think of a file object, for example. You can only iterate over that once.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, generator functions are just syntactic sugar for classes with a **next** function. Example:

```
>>> def f():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i


>>> x = f()
>>> x
<generator object f at 0x0000000000659938>
>>> next(x)
1
>>> next(x)
2
>>> next(x)
3
>>> class g(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0

    def __next__(self):
        self.i += 1
        return self.i


>>> y = g()
>>> y
<__main__.g object at 0x000000000345D908>
>>> next(y)
1
>>> next(y)
2
>>> next(y)
3
```

In fact, I came here looking to see if there *is* any significant difference. Please shout if there is.

So, to answer the question, what you have is a class with a __next__ method that returns an object that also has a __next__ method. So the simplest thing to do would be to replace your `yield` with a `return` and to keep track of how far along you are, and to remember to raise a StopIteration when you reach the end of the array. So something like:

```
class MyString:
    def __init__(self,s):
        self.s=s
        self._i = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self._i += 1
        if self._i >= len(self.s):
            raise StopIteration
        return self.s[self._i]
```

That's probably the simplest way to achieve what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

## OBSERVATION

If `next()` function calls `__next__()` method, what's happening in the following example.

Code:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = 10
        
    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range(self.s):
            yield i
    
    def __next__(self):
        print('__next__ method is called.')
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    obj = T()
    k = iter(obj)
    print(next(k)) #0
    print(next(k)) #1
    print(next(k)) #2
    print(next(k)) #3
    print(next(k)) #4
    print(next(k)) #5
    print(next(k)) #6
    print(next(k)) #7
    print(next(k)) #8
    print(next(k)) #9
    print(next(k))
    print(next(k))
```

Terminal:

```
C:...>python test.py
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(next(k))
StopIteration
```

### WHAT IS HAPPENING?

It seams that `next()` function does not calling `__next__` method. I cannot understand why [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) states that "`next(iterator, default)` Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its `__next__()` method." **If someonw knows, let us help!**

## Case: `__iter__` with `__next__` in custom class with `yield`

So, if you want to use `yield` (in order to create a generator) with `__iter__` and `__next__` methods in a custom `class`, **do not put** just the `yield` into the `__next__` method, **but** use it with `__iter__(self)` and `return self.__next__()` instead `return self`.

Code:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = 10
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.__next__()
    
    def __next__(self):
        for i in range(self.s):
            yield i
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    obj = T()
    for i in obj:
        print(i)
```

Terminal:

```
C:\...>python test.py
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

C:...>
```

Also, you can call from `__iter__` any other method instead `__next__()`.

Code:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = 10
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.foo()
    
    def foo(self):
        for i in range(self.s):
            yield i
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    obj = T()
    for i in obj:
        print(i)
```

You will have exactly the same results.

## Case: `yield` in `__iter__` method without `__next__` method

I don't think it is a good idea to use `yield` in `__iter__`. Ok, it works, but I think that destroys the class API.

## Case: `__iter__` with `__next__` in custom class without `yield`

Use these methods (`__iter__` and `__next__`). In the `__iter__` `return self` and do not forget to `raise StopIteration` in `__next__` method.

Code:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = 10
        
    def __iter__(self):
        self.__i = -1
        return self
    
    def __next__(self):
        while  self.__i < self.s-1:
            self.__i+=1
            return self.__i
        raise StopIteration
    
if __name__== '__main__':
    obj = T()
    for i in obj:
        print(i)
```

Comment: In your first example, with `k=iter(obj)` you are obtaining a generator object for the `range` (this is returned by that `yield`), upon which you successively call `next`, so you never actually try to call `T.next()`