# How to unpack an object as it was a tuple in a for loop?

Tags: python, iterator, generator, python-3.6, iterable-unpacking

I tried create the following code:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg1 = arg + 1
        self.arg2 = arg + 2
        self.arg3 = arg + 3

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        yield self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3


test_list = [Test(0), Test(1), Test(2)]

for arg1, arg2, arg3 in test_list:
    print('arg1', arg1, 'arg2', arg2, 'arg3', arg3)
```

But when I try to run, python says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    for arg1, arg2, arg3 in test_list:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

I can work around it by unpacking by hand:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg1 = arg + 1
        self.arg2 = arg + 2
        self.arg3 = arg + 3

test_list = [Test(0), Test(1), Test(2)]

for test in test_list:
    arg1, arg2, arg3 = test.arg1, test.arg2, test.arg3
    print('arg1', arg1, 'arg2', arg2, 'arg3', arg3)
```

How can we unpack objects in a python list without doing it explicitly as the workaround demonstrated? For the last example, the result would be like:

```
arg1 1 arg2 2 arg3 3
arg1 2 arg2 3 arg3 4
arg1 3 arg2 4 arg3 5
```

Comment: Not sure if duplicate, but definitely very closely related: [when i do yield from inside \_\_next\_\_. why does it return generator object?](//stackoverflow.com/q/37929956)

Comment: Disregarding the yield problem, this usage of iteration is unusual. It produces an infinite repetition (1) of the same value (2) and these two facts together conceal that each iteration uses the same iterator. That would be a bug for every other usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are close, however, you need to `yield` the values in the `__iter__` method, not the `__next__` method:

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self, arg):
    self.arg1 = arg + 1
    self.arg2 = arg + 2
    self.arg3 = arg + 3
  def __iter__(self):
    yield from [self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3]

for a, b, c in [Test(0), Test(1), Test(2)]:
  pass
```

`yield self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3` will give a `tuple` result `(1, 2, 3)` which, when iterating over the list, requires additional unpacking i.e:

```
for [(a, b, c)] in [Test(0), Test(1), Test(2)]:
  pass
```

Thus, in order to avoid the additional unpacking in the loop, you have to create a stream of generated values by looping over the attributes and yielding each, one at a time.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your `__next__` method isn't implemented correctly. You made the `Test` class iterable, but it doesn't iterate how you think it does:

```
>>> itr = iter(Test(0))
>>> next(itr)
<generator object Test.__next__ at 0x7ff609ade9a8>
>>> next(itr)
<generator object Test.__next__ at 0x7ff609ade930>
>>> next(itr)
<generator object Test.__next__ at 0x7ff609ade9a8>
```

Instead of yielding a `(self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3)` tuple, it yields generators. This is caused by your use of `yield` inside the `__next__` method. A `__next__` method should *return* values, not *yield* them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37929956) for a detailed explanation and fix.

Answer (score 2):

`__next__` is useful if you have a variable number of items to return. Since you have a fixed number of attributes to yield from your iterator, you can simply use the `iter` function to create an iterator from the three attributes and make the `__iter__` method return the iterator instead:

```
class Test(object):

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg1 = arg + 1
        self.arg2 = arg + 2
        self.arg3 = arg + 3

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter((self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3))
```

which is equivalent to, without using the `iter` function:

```
class Test(object):
    class Iter:
        def __init__(self, lst):
            self.lst = lst
            self.index = 0

        def __next__(self):
            if self.index == len(self.lst):
                raise StopIteration()
            value = self.lst[self.index]
            self.index += 1
            return value

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg1 = arg + 1
        self.arg2 = arg + 2
        self.arg3 = arg + 3

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.Iter((self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3))
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: How to unpack an object as it was a tuple in a for loop?

You are wrong, you get a `Test(object)` in the loop.
To get a `tuple(arg1, arg2, arg3)` from the object, you have to trigger it.

1. using `iter`:

   ```
   class Test(object):
      ...
      def __iter__(self):
          yield self.arg1
          yield self.arg2
          yield self.arg3


   for arg1, arg2, arg3 in map(iter, test_list):
       print('arg1', arg1, 'arg2', arg2, 'arg3', arg3)
   ```

   or force `.format(...` to see `t` as type `tuple`:

   ```
   for t in test_list:
       print("arg1={}, arg2={}, arg3={}".format(*tuple(t)))
   ```

---

2. using class property `values(self, ...`:

   ```
   class Test(object):
      ...
       #@property
       def values(self):
           return self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3


   for arg1, arg2, arg3 in map(Test.values, test_list):
       print('arg1', arg1, 'arg2', arg2, 'arg3', arg3)
   ```

   or with **`.format(...`** and **`*`**

   ```
   for t in test_list:
       print("arg1={}, arg2={}, arg3={}".format(*t.values()))
   ```

---

3. Recommend usage. without any **magic**:

   ```
   for t in test_list:
       print('arg1', t.arg1, 'arg2', t.arg2, 'arg3', t.arg3)
   ```

   or with `.format(...`

   ```
   for t in test_list:
       print("arg1={t.arg1}, arg2={t.arg2}, arg3={t.arg3}".format(t=t))
   ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***